# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sbt.cross.CrossVersionUtil

Tags: java, scala, sbt

Using xUbuntu VM;
Running sbt command returns a stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/cross/CrossVersionUtil$
at sbt.BuildPaths$.binarySbtVersion(BuildPaths.scala:60)
at sbt.BuildPaths$.getGlobalBase(BuildPaths.scala:20)
at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:30)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:481)
...
```

---

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

---

```
Scala code runner version 2.11.7
```

---

```
sbt: 0.13.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me was to downgrade sbt:
from 0.13.9
to 0.13.8

used commands:

```
curl -LOk http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.8.deb
sudo dpkg -i sbt-0.13.8.deb
rm sbt-0.13.8.deb
```